# How to use a for loop for a registry edit script

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, printing, registry

So I need to write a batch script that changes the SNMP Community string in the registry for a printer from "public" to something I define; for the sake of this lets just say "notpublic". If I have a machine with only one printer I know I can write something like this

```
reg add "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\Standard TCP/IP Port\Ports\10.226.70.248" /v "SNMP Community" /t REG_SZ /d notpublic /f 
net stop spooler
net start spooler
```

But more than likely, there will be multiple printers/ports that will need to be changed. How can I use something like a For loop that basically says

```
FOR: [every sub directory in the directory HKLM\System\...\Ports]
DO: /v "SNMP Community" /t REG_SZ /d notpublic /f
```

I'm still kind of new at writing scripts so if there is an even easier way to achieve this, I'm all ears! Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at `for /?`

Comment: Look at `reg query /?` as well.